# How to get underlining to work inside table

Tags: css

I'm trying to get text color to change and the text to be underlined when the link is selected (it will have class "selected"). For some reason I can't get it to work even with !important. And yes, I know "a" should be inside "li" :)

HTML:

```
<a href="">
<li class="list selected">
<table>
<tr><td class="first">Text here</td><td class="second"><div class="icon-arrow-down"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</li>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    .selected {
        color:green !important;
        text-decoration:underline !important;
    }
}
```

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vwLu8/1/.

Comment: the syntax you are using is not CSS (see answer of @SW4). You are using scss syntax: http://sass-lang.com/ you can activate scss for jsFiddle in the languages ribbon: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/vwLu8/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors should not be nested unless you're using a preprocessor, you also need to change your level of specificity, change your CSS to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/vwLu8/2/)

```
.selected table td{
    color:green;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[**More on specificity from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the ***most relevant to an element and gets to be applied***.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.